# Get the CAS key once the server redirects to our webpage

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cas

The problem is once i login to an external server where the data is present and to get the data i am using GET/POST requests, But  unity is throwing the cross domain policy errors for the Webplayer version of the game since our game is hosted on a different domain and we are making Post/get request get data from the external server.
So the point is once the login is complete in the external server it redirects me to my domain page with a CAS ticket attached to it in the end like this:

http://mydomain.com/webbuild.html?ticket=ST-260-NigEPjMAlD7GoeRsxAIO-xxx-cas

That server page has this code in it:

```
<div class="content">

    <div class="content-center float-left">
        <form id="fm1" action="/cas/login;jsessionid=qjuydeza6epg18b644x1e25ly?service=https%3A%2F%2Fsb.xxx.com%2Fweb%2Fplayer_login%3FapiKey%3D285dcdb0-9e8b-4e17-8a2f-f72551a16f3d%26successUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fmydomain.com%252Fwebbuild.html" method="post">

            <div id="error-message" class="error display-none">

            </div>




            <h2>LOG IN</h2>
            <div class="row">

        <input id="username" name="username" class="required display-block" tabindex="1" placeholder="Email address" type="email" accesskey="u" value="" size="25" autocomplete="false"/>

            </div>
            <div class="row">


        <input id="password" name="password" class="required display-block" tabindex="2" placeholder="Password" accesskey="p" type="password" value="" size="25" autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>
            <div class="row buttons">
        <input type="hidden" name="lt" value="LT-1182-FT6sa9JS2ASrsjEpiEqV0eJ3Pr3fBI" />
        <input type="hidden" name="execution" value="e1s1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_eventId" value="submit" />

                <input class="submit-button" name="submit" accesskey="l" value="Log In" tabindex="4" type="submit" />
            </div>
 <div class="row links">



                <a id="forgot_password_link" href="https://sb.xxx.com/web/users/forgotten_passwords/new" class="portal-link display-block">Forgot your password?</a>

                    <a id="create_account_link" href="https://sb.xxx.com/web/users/new" class="portal-link display-block">Join bspot!</a>

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="content-right content-border float-left">&nbsp;</div>
</div>




        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/cas/js/cas.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/cas/js/ga.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/cas/js/urchin.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/cas/js/call_urchin.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={});NREUM.info={"applicationID":"2220950","applicationTime":36,"beacon":"beacon-2.newrelic.com","queueTime":0,"licenseKey":"099091ce43","transactionName":"blBbNkoFXBIDVRJdXFcaczFoS2UkIBsvenUWQ1AHT0tYEhIZAlFVWEBVFmdLRwhNVQdHf1ZSUAxuDVcWTFwVRA==","agent":"js-agent.newrelic.com\/nr-378.min.js","errorBeacon":"jserror.newrelic.com"}</script></body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to read the CAS key from their server? either through webplayer version of the build(which requires crossdomain.xml in their server which i don't have access to) or from and native application lets say (pc,android,ios) builds. If there is a way which library should i use to read that CAS ticket once it redirects.

Do i have to have a html code in my domain page where it reads the CAS ticket?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what you are doing, but here is how an interaction with CAS typically occurs:

1. User hits the application webpage.
2. Application redirects user to CAS.
3. CAS, using standard cookies and sessions, determines if user is already logged in.
4. if User is not logged in, CAS displays a login form for the user to provide login credentials. IF the user is already logged in, CAS skips to step #7.
5. CAS then interacts with the authentication data to verify that the provided credentials are valid.
6. if they are, then CAS logs in the user.
7. then CAS will redirect back to the application, providing a ticket.
8. The application makes a direct call to CAS to validate the provided ticket.
9. If the ticket is valid, then CAS returns user information as a response to the request.
10. The application then creates an authenticated session for the user, potentially looking up user information based on the info provided by CAS, and redirects them wherever is appropriate.

So, your application server should be able to turn around and make a request to the CAS server, using the ticket to get user information.

Since this is all happening via redirects or server originated requests, different domains should not be an issue.

Hope this helps.